# confused about effects vs. means parameterization in R - which is right for Anova?

Tags: r, anova, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, glmm

I'm running a few GLMs and using the effects (e.g. glm(var1~var2...) ) and then means parameterization (i.e. glm(var1~-1+var2...) -- the one without the intercept). I understand that effects gives you the relationship among your variables and means gives you the actual mean values for your groups, but when I'm doing an Anova() to evaluate significance of my fixed and random effects, I get different results (e.g. significant or not) depending on whether I use means or effects. Why is this? I vaguely recall that I should be evaluating significance only with the effects parameterization.
Is that accurate or am I remembering this the wrong way?

Is the general idea that you get your coefficients from the means param and then go back to your effects to assess significance? Also, if you're using your confidence intervals to evaluate if 2 groups are different, do you do this before backtransforming your CIs and coefs or after backtransforming your CIs and coefs (and I am doing this from the effects or means parameterization)?

Comment: You must remove `-1` from your formula. For conventional anova, the total sum of squares (TSS) is $\sum (y-\bar y)^2$ but if you remove the intercept from the model in R then the TSS becomes $\sum y^2$ and $n\bar y^2$ gets incorporated instead into the treatment SS. That's not what you want, so keep the intercept in.

Comment: you should define what is effects  parameterization ? and what is its purpose ?